# Formik's forms don't recognize material UI component's text field value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, formik, formik-material-ui

I built a simple contact page using formik and material UI. Everything works except for when I use the Material UI components instead of regular input tags. It seems like the program can't read the value inside the Material UI `TextField` component.

This works:

```
                     <Field 
                        name="name" 
                        id="outlined-textarea"
                            label="First Name"
                            variant="outlined"
                            margin="dense"
                            component='input'
                            />
                    <ErrorMessage name="name" className="errorMsg" component="p" />
```

This doesn't work:

```
                      <Field
                        name="lastName"
                        id="outlined-textarea"
                        label="Last Name"
                        component={TextField}
                        variant="outlined"
                        margin="dense"
                    />
         <ErrorMessage name="lastName" className="errorMsg" component="p" />
```

I created a sandbox of the code [here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-meadow-pc8xm?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hook formik properly with material ui, use [render](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/field#render) prop (instead of `component`) and grab the formik `field` which you get and pass it down to material ui `Textfield`

**Like this**

```js
<Field
    name="lastName"
    id="outlined-textarea"
    label="Last Name"
    render={({ field }) => <TextField {...field} />}
    variant="outlined"
    margin="dense"
  />
```